# How I can create Webcenter Portal Application from JDeveloper 12c?

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, webcenter

When I want to create WebCenter Portal Application from JDeveloper 12c, I can't find this option in the gallery, how I usually do this from JDeveloper 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the WebCenter extension using help->check for updates
(or get it from here - http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/156082.xml#oracle.asset-publishing-ext )

Comment: Which one, Details for WebCenter Portal Design Time!? The window with updates is empty. Maybe I have all updates, but I still can't find "WebCenter Portal Application". I have only three options: WebCenter Portal Asset Application, WebCenter Portal Server Extension, and WebCenter Portlet Producer Application.

Comment: Try adding all of them - you can download the zips from: http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/156082.xml and then use the check for update to point to the local copy of the zip.

Answer (score 0):

The Portal Asset Application lets you create the portal assets (page templates, layouts, skins, content presenter templates, etc) that can be deployed to your webcenter portal. Portlet producer similarly let's you create portlet producer applications that can be used in webcenter.